# Why my tikz image falls out of page margin?

Tags: tikz-pgf, crop

I am trying to draw a simple dependency graph using `tikz` and `lualatex`. I can't figure out why the result falls out of page... Here is the code and the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikz[nodes={text depth=.2em, draw, fill=white}, rounded corners]
\graph[tree layout,  grow=down]  {
"Rule Manager"->{
    "Module Base"->{
        "Communicator"
        },
    "Log Data"->{
        "Communicator", 
        "ODB Oracle"
        }, 
    "Rule Manager Status"->{
        "Status Base", 
        "Rule Base"
        },
    "Rules"->{
        "Rule Base", 
        "Profiles"->{
            "Message"->{
                "Communicator", 
                "Interface SOAP", 
                "ODB Utils"
                },
            "Profile Base"
            }
        },
    "Threadpool"
    };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: cropped image]

**Update:** The image is not wider that the page width. Adding more nodes, pushes it further right:

[image: Partial graph]
[image: Completed graph]

Comment: Because it is wider than the text width. There is just not enough space for those nodes on one line in that font size

Comment: @daleif It is not wider.

Comment: try to center the image with \begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}....\end{tikzpicture}\end{center} .. maybe this action solve your problem

Comment: Have you tried `\fbox{..} ` around the entire tikzpicture. Then we can see what latex thinks the size is. You can also ask tikzpicture to draw its own boundingbox, it might not be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\tikz` command inside the `tikzpicture` environment is wrong. You should use either, but not both in combination. Add the options directly to the environment and you should be fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs, graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={text depth=.2em, draw, fill=white}, rounded corners]
\graph[tree layout,  grow=down]  {
"Rule Manager"->{
    "Module Base"->{
        "Communicator"
        },
    "Log Data"->{
        "Communicator", 
        "ODB Oracle"
        }, 
    "Rule Manager Status"->{
        "Status Base", 
        "Rule Base"
        },
    "Rules"->{
        "Rule Base", 
        "Profiles"->{
            "Message"->{
                "Communicator", 
                "Interface SOAP", 
                "ODB Utils"
                },
            "Profile Base"
            }
        },
    "Threadpool"
    };
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\tikz{`[...]`}` macro means essentially the same as `\begin{tikzpicture}`[...]`\end{tikzpicture}`. Nesting these command can lead to strange results. :)